# unable to update the column to the excel file which is checkout from perforce

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, perforce, python-jira

i have a code where i was reading the Excel file from Perforce and storing it to the local.
then doing some other work like:
-- read all sheets 
-- search for particular columns and extract that column data.
-- and from that data extract the other info from JIRA.
Till here its working fine so once we got all the data we will create a dataframe and then search for the column "STATUS" if there update the column with same data otherwise create a column in the same sheet and write the data to the column.
**Code:**

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from jira import JIRA
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from openpyxl import load_workbook


def getStatus(issueID):
    jiraURL='http://in-jira-test:0000' #Test server
    options = {'server': jiraURL}

    jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=(userName, password))

    """Getting the status for the particular issueID"""
    issue = jira.issue(issueID)
    status = issue.fields.status
    return status

def getFileFromPerforce():
    """
        Getting the file from perforce
    """
    p4File = ' "//depot/Planning/Configurations.xlsx" '
    p4Localfile = "C:/depot/Planning/Configurations.xlsx"
    global p4runcmd
    p4runcmd = p4Cmd + " sync -f " + p4File
    stream = os.popen(p4runcmd)
    output = stream.read()
    print(output)

    return p4File, p4Localfile

def excelReader():

    # function call to get the filepath
    p4FileLocation, filePath = getFileFromPerforce()

    xls=pd.ExcelFile(filePath)

    # gets the all sheets names in a list
    sheetNameList = xls.sheet_names

    for sheets in sheetNameList:
        data=pd.read_excel(filePath,sheet_name=sheets)

        # Checking the Jira column availability in all sheets
        if any("Jira" in columnName for columnName in data.columns):
            Value = data['Jira']
            colValue=Value.to_frame()

            # Getting the status of particular jira issue and updating to the dataframe
            for row,rowlen in zip(colValue.iterrows(), range(len(colValue))):
                stringData=row[1].to_string()

                # getting the issueID from the jira issue url
                issueID = stringData.partition('/')[2].rsplit('/')[3]
                status = getStatus(issueID)

                # data.set_value(k, 'Status', status) #---> deprecated
                data.at[rowlen, "Status"]=status

            # writting the data to the same excel sheet
            print("filePath-",filePath)
            excelBook = load_workbook(filePath)
            with ExcelWriter(filePath, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
                # Save the file workbook as base
                writer.book = excelBook
                writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in excelBook.worksheets)

                # Creating the new column Status and writing to the sheet which having jira column
                data.to_excel(writer, sheets, index=False)

                # Save the file
                writer.save()

        else:
            continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # read userName and passwrod from account file
    f = open("account.txt", "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    userName = str(lines[0].rstrip())
    password = str(lines[1].rstrip())
    AdminUser = str(lines[2].rstrip())
    AdminPassword = str(lines[3].rstrip())
    p4Cmd = 'p4 -c snehil_tool -p indperforce:1444 -u %s -P %s '%(AdminUser,AdminPassword)
    f.close
    excelReader()
```

In this code i'm not able to write the data inside the file which i have checkout from perforce i was getting the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/snsingh/PycharmProjects/DemoProgram/JiraStatusUpdate/updateStatusInOpticalFile.py", line 105, in <module>
    excelReader()
  File "C:/Users/snsingh/PycharmProjects/DemoProgram/JiraStatusUpdate/updateStatusInOpticalFile.py", line 88, in excelReader
    writer.save()
  File "C:\Users\snsingh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 779, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\snsingh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 783, in close
    return self.save()
  File "C:\Users\snsingh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 44, in save
    return self.book.save(self.path)
  File "C:\Users\snsingh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 392, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\snsingh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 291, in save_workbook
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
  File "C:\Users\snsingh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 1204, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/depot/Planning/Configurations.xlsx'
```

This piece of code is not working from the above code:

```
# writting the data to the same excel sheet
print("filePath-",filePath)
excelBook = load_workbook(filePath)
with ExcelWriter(filePath, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
# Save the file workbook as base
writer.book = excelBook
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in excelBook.worksheets)

# Creating the new column Status and writing to the sheet which having jira column
data.to_excel(writer, sheets, index=False)

# Save the file
writer.save()
```

**NOTE:**
This code works fine with local file contain the same data and its able to write perfectly. but its only happens when i readed the file from perforce.
Even i have given all the permission to the folder and tried with different folder path but i got the same error .Please tell me where i'm making mistake any help would be grate or any questions please fill free to write in comment.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1. When you get the file from Perforce, use `p4 sync` instead of `p4 sync -f`.
2. After you `p4 sync` the file, `p4 edit` it.  That makes it writable so that you can *edit* it.
3. After you save your edits to the file, `p4 submit` it.  That puts your changes in the depot.

Comment: thanks for reply but i have some doubt : if see my code i have stored that file in my local which is given as "p4Localfile " so why can we not directly use the file like that .
not sure about p4 edit Is it allow me to the same operation like update or create new columns like same i'm doing in my code or i need to update that part of code

Comment: You're getting the "permission denied" error because the local file is not writable.  The `p4 edit` makes the local file writable.  What part of that do you have doubts about?  :)

Comment: plz can tell me diff. b/w p4 sync and p4 sync -f ?.
Can u tell me where should i add p4 edit in my code not sure where to add that

Comment: Put the `p4 edit` any time after the `p4 sync` and before you attempt to write to the local file.  If you don't know what a command flag does, don't use it!  The default behavior is usually the correct one; most optional flags to p4 commands enable behavior that is more complex and/or less safe.